# High upvote count on funny but irrelevant answers

Tags: discussion, up-votes

See this - [What is JSON-P & how do you pronounce it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306344/what-is-json-p-how-do-you-pronounce-it/1306375#1306375)

Can anyone explain this effect?

I think it demonstrates the side effect of having a penalty on down votes.

**Update:**
This answer is half-correct and still accumulated up-votes.

Don't you guys think it tells me this:
a) Post funny answers and get an overnight reputation boost.
b) Fun + messy stuff > best stuff

Some food for thought...

Comment: I'd agree with your last statement.  However, I believe the answer is technically correct.  So, I suppose it deserves upvotes.

Comment: How's that answer irrelevant? It's not complete, but part of the question was about the pronounciation. I'm not sure the answerer was even aware of Jonathon's "relevation".

Comment: ROFL. Thanks for posting. Wouldn't have encountered that question otherwise. Oh, we like humor. And yes, the answer is technically correct.

Comment: it was half-correct, that's why I believe it was not selected as a best answer.

Comment: Warrior, how do you pronounce JSON-P?

Comment: Damn, I so wish I could correct typos in comments...

Comment: Jayson - Pea

Comment: @balpha It's ok, we have all done it.

Comment: His answer is the only one to address the pronunciation.  Everyone else already took care of the "What Is?" part of his question.  I wouldn't really worry about it.  I don't see this happening often/ever.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It did technically answer the OP's question, so I think it was ok in this case.

And you got to have some humor when programming, you will go insane if you don't.

Comment: Most of us are already insane though...

Comment: insane enough to kidnap one of TheTXI ponies? And can't forget Welbog's lasers!

Comment: We are insane enough to have discussions about posts with the word 'Pee' in them.

Comment: I call it sense of humor. Others call it insanity...

Comment: @jjnguy: wait till you have kids, you'll be talking about all kinds of details about poop: color, texture, odor, consistency. And you'll forget that other people get kind of grossed out by it...

Comment: Oh great...and that part of my life is rushing up on me too...I can't wait!

Answer (score 10):

People like humor.

And waffles.

See?!

Comment: Yeah, but that was not the whole idea behind having upvotes and downvotes and sorting them.

Comment: You should only be concerned with "sorting" when it's CW. All non-cw questions should be voted based upon your approval of the answer exclusively, and not its relationship to other answers.

Comment: The purpose is to get good answers to the top and bad answers to the bottom.  What is good and bad is community-defined.  Being software people, almost all of us who have survived have a sense of humor.

Comment: @Jonathan: I'm always concerned about an answers relationship to me. did it send me flowers? Would I bring it home to meet my parents? These are important questions to ask.

Comment: Does it put out?

Comment: now with more waffliness!

Answer (score 5):

It looks like the only answer to address the phonetic pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

I upvoted it...only because it was technically correct. The OP asked how to pronounce it, and "Jayson Pee" is correct. Now, if that answer had been "accepted," I would have been upset.

Comment: Hehe, you said 'Pee'!!

Comment: Ewwwww! Potty-mouth!